# Most efficient way to create a tree like structure from a large JSON file

Tags: python, json, recursion, pyspark, tree

I have a large JSON file like the following:

```
[(3, (2, 'Child')), (2, (1, 'Parent')), (1, (None, 'Root'))]
```

where the key of each element is a unique index for that element and 1st element in the value pair signifies the index of its parent element.

Now, the ultimate goal is to convert this JSON file into the following:

```
[(3, (2, 'Child Parent Root')), (2, (1, 'Parent Root')), (1, (None, 'Root'))]
```

where the 2nd element in the value pair for each item will be modified such that it has the concatenation of all the values up to its root ancestor.

The no. of levels is not fixed and can be up to 256. I know I can solve this problem by creating a tree DS and traversing it but the problem is the JSON file is huge (almost 180M items in the list).

Any idea on how can I achieve this efficiently? Suggestions involving Apache Spark would be fine as well.

Comment: Can we assume parent must have smaller index than children?

Comment: Yes, that can be assumed.

Comment: The JSON file you present is not JSON. JSON does not know the syntax of tuples, nor does it consider single quotes as string delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a breadth-first search to find all ancestor element chains:

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
d, d1 = [(3, (2, 'Child')), (2, (1, 'Parent')), (1, (None, 'Root'))], defaultdict(list)
for a, (b, c) in d:
   d1[b].append((a, c))

q, r = deque([(1, d1[None][0][1])]), {}
while q:
   r[n[0]] = (n:=q.popleft())[1]
   q.extend([(a, b+' '+n[1]) for a, b in d1[n[0]]])
```

Now, `r` stores the ancestor values for each element:

```
{1: 'Root', 2: 'Parent Root', 3: 'Child Parent Root'}
```

Then, using a list comprehension to update `d`:

```
result = [(a, (b, r[a])) for a, (b, _) in d]
```

Output:

```
[(3, (2, 'Child Parent Root')), (2, (1, 'Parent Root')), (1, (None, 'Root'))]
```

An iterative approach such as BFS will eliminate the possibility of a `RecursionError` which might occur when running DFS on a very large graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is correct but does not seem to be efficient enough for ~180M items in the <d> array. Getting "Killed" error while processing the given "while" loop.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark this is treated a `Graph` problem and solved using [`Vertex Centric Programming`](https://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/%7Edell/teaching/cc/paper/sigmod10/p135-malewicz.pdf). Unfortunately, [`GraphX`](https://spark.apache.org/graphx/) does not have a python compatible API.

Another option is to use [`graphframes`](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/api/python/index.html).

I have included here a logic using joins which mimics `Vertex Centric Programming` but without using any libraries. Provided you can convert the data representation you have into a dataframe with `id`, `parent_id` and `name` column.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col as c
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("nsankaranara").getOrCreate() 

data = [(6, 3, "Child_3", ),
        (5, 2, "Child_2", ),
        (4, 2, "Child_1", ),
        (3, 1, "Parent_2", ), 
        (2, 1, "Parent_1", ), 
        (1, None, "Root"), ]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id", "parent_id", "name", ))

df = (df.withColumn("mapped_parent_id", c("parent_id"))
        .withColumn("visited", F.lit(False)))

start_nodes = df.filter(c("mapped_parent_id").isNull())

# Controls how deep we want to traverse
max_iter = 256
iter_counter = 0

# Iteratively identify the next child and add your name to them
while iter_counter < max_iter:
    iter_counter += 1
    df = (df.alias("a").join(start_nodes.alias("b"), 
                            ((c("a.parent_id") == c("b.id")) | (c("a.id") == c("b.id"))), how="left_outer"))
    df = (df.select(c("a.id"), 
                  c("a.parent_id"),
                  (F.when((c("b.id").isNotNull() & (c("a.id") != c("b.id"))), F.lit(None)).otherwise(c("a.mapped_parent_id"))).alias("mapped_parent_id"),
                  F.when((c("a.id") != c("b.id")), F.concat_ws(" ", c("a.name"), c("b.name"))).otherwise(c("a.name")).alias("name"),
                  (F.when(c("a.id") == c("b.id"), F.lit(True)).otherwise(c("a.visited"))).alias("visited")
                  )).cache()
    
    start_nodes = df.filter(((c("mapped_parent_id").isNull()) & (c("visited") == False)))
    if start_nodes.count() == 0:
        # signifies that all nodes have been visited
        break

df.select("id", "parent_id", "name").show(truncate = False)
```

### Output

```
+---+---------+---------------------+
|id |parent_id|name                 |
+---+---------+---------------------+
|6  |3        |Child_3 Parent_2 Root|
|5  |2        |Child_2 Parent_1 Root|
|4  |2        |Child_1 Parent_1 Root|
|3  |1        |Parent_2 Root        |
|2  |1        |Parent_1 Root        |
|1  |null     |Root                 |
+---+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I am repeatedly getting this error while going with this implementation. "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs. You can increase the timeout for broadcasts via spark.sql.broadcastTimeout or disable broadcast join by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1"...I have tried both disabling broadcast join and increasing broadcast timeout but nothing worked. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Disabling `autoBroadcastJoin` should work imo. However another option is to cache the `df` after the `select`. This will break the lineage chain and reduce the time taken to broadcast.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the `cache` after select.